# How do I fix this race condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition

I have a server accepting clients that has a `stop()` method that closes the server down, which is causing a `java.nio.AsynchronousCloseException` that I'd like to resolve. The `stop()` method is called on a different thread, which is what is causing the race condition I believe.

Here is my code:

```
public void run() {
    InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(provider.getConnection(), 12354);
    try {
        server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        server.configureBlocking(true);
        server.socket().bind(addr);
        parent.setIP(addr.getAddress().getHostAddress().toString());
        password = generatePassword();
        parent.setPassword(password);
        parent.setStatus("Ready.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        parent.die("Could not start server: " + e.getMessage());
        runner = null;
    }
    while (runner == Thread.currentThread()) {
        try {
            SocketChannel sc = server.accept();
            if (available) {
                session = new ReceiveSession(this, sc, password, addr.getAddress());
                session.start();
                available = false;
            } else {
                new ReceiveBusyHandler(sc).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            synchronized (swallowException) {
                if (!swallowException) {
                    parent.showError(e.toString());
                }
                available = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void stop() throws IOException {
    synchronized (swallowException) {
        swallowException = true;
        runner = null;
        if (server != null) {
            server.socket().close();
            server.close();
        }

        swallowException = false;
        System.out.println("Server down");
    }
}
```

(FYI, `swallowException` is a `Boolean` and you can see I've tried synchronizing it.)

It looks like the `stop()` method is setting `swallowException` to `true` and then back to `false` before the exception handler in my server loop has a chance to access it.

UPDATE: I introduced a new `Object` to use as a lock, and used `wait()/notify()` to fix my issue:

```
public void run() {
        InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(provider.getConnection(), 12354);
        try {
            server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            server.configureBlocking(true);
            server.socket().bind(addr);
            parent.setIP(addr.getAddress().getHostAddress().toString());
            password = generatePassword();
            parent.setPassword(password);
            parent.setStatus("Ready.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            parent.die("Could not start server: " + e.getMessage());
            runner = null;
        }
        while (runner == Thread.currentThread()) {
            try {
                SocketChannel sc = server.accept();
                if (available) {
                    session = new ReceiveSession(this, sc, password, addr.getAddress());
                    session.start();
                    available = false;
                } else {
                    new ReceiveBusyHandler(sc).start();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    if (!swallowException) {
                        parent.showError(e.toString());

                    }
                    lock.notify();
                    available = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws IOException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            swallowException = true;
            runner = null;
            if (server != null) {
                server.socket().close();
                server.close();
            }
            while (swallowException) {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                    swallowException = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            //swallowException = false;
            System.out.println("Server down");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, synchronization is done on an object, not on a variable. When you synchronize on `swallowException`, you synchronize on its value (`Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`). This is not what you want. You should synchronize on the object that contains `swallowException`.

Comment: I see. So I should use `synchronized(this)`?

Comment: Fixed it. I added a `private final Object lock = new Object();` to my class variables, synchronized on that lock, and used a `lock.wait()` in my `stop()` method and a `lock.notify()` in my exception handler.

Answer (score 1):

This part is not correctly synchronized:

```
synchronized (swallowException) {
    swallowException = true;
```

You are synchronizing on one instance (`false`) and immediately changing the `swallowException` *reference* to point to a different instance (`true`). The next thread to enter `stop` won't block.

Either synchronize on an instance that won't be swapped out (the owner of these methods) or use some other locking mechanism from `java.util.concurrent`.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise refactoring your code (even the solution you posted as an update), because it's just not clear what's happening.

From your *description*, it seems like you just want a thread-safe way to stop your server.  I recommend doing this, whereby you simply [call close() on the ServerSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2983860/119114), and be able to catch a `SocketException`:

```
private boolean cont = true;

// this can safely be called from any thread
public synchronized void stop() {
    cont = false;
    if (server != null) {
       server.socket().close();
    }
}
private synchronized void setContinue(boolean value) {
    cont = value;
}
private synchronized boolean shouldContinue() {
    return cont;
}
private synchronized void openChannel() {
    server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
}

public void run() {
    InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(provider.getConnection(), 12354);
    try {
        openChannel();
        server.configureBlocking(true);
        server.socket().bind(addr);
        parent.setIP(addr.getAddress().getHostAddress().toString());
        password = generatePassword();
        parent.setPassword(password);
        parent.setStatus("Ready.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        parent.die("Could not start server: " + e.getMessage());
        setContinue(false);
    }

    while (shouldContinue()) {
        try {
            SocketChannel sc = server.accept();
            if (shouldContinue()) {
                if (available) {
                    session = new ReceiveSession(this, sc, password, addr.getAddress());
                    session.start();
                    available = false;
                } else {
                    new ReceiveBusyHandler(sc).start();
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException se) {
            // normal shutdown from stop()
        } catch (IOException e) {
            parent.showError(e.toString()); 
            available = true;               
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Server down");
}
```

[See more about this technique for stopping a server here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3421617/119114)

Comment: This won't break out of the `while` loop because the thread is blocking on `SocketChannel sc = server.accept();`. That's why I have to close the server forcefully, to break out from that `accept()` block.

Comment: Were it not for that, this is definitely the method I would use.

Comment: Gotcha.  Can you just use a call to `ServerSocket#close()` in the `stop()` method?  Then, your loop will break out with a `SocketException` which you catch, and move on?  Is it that you're trying to implement this entirely without exceptions?

Comment: I just want to close it down without the user having to worry about any errors, which is why I swallow that exception ONLY when I close down the server. If there are any other errors/exceptions they should be reported properly. If I caught `SocketException` and just ignore it that will mask some legitimate exceptions that could occur, so I just went with the general exception and report all of them. At some stage I will probably deal with more specific exceptions but for now this will do.

Comment: I think you can safely catch just the `SocketException`, and have a separate handler for other `IOException` instances (see my update if you're interested).  The final code you posted just seems to have too many variables to track, and is a bit too confusing.  Any time I see confusing code that's supposed to work in a multi-threaded environment, I get a little nervous.  But, that's just me :)

Comment: Like I said, `SocketException` can be thrown for other legitimate cases (for example, I believe when a socket is closed a `SocketException` is thrown) but I get what you're saying. At the moment this isn't too high on the priority list, it's just been bugging me for a while (excuse the pun). It may be confusing to you but I understand it :) I'm sure I'll get to clean up at some point, but this is still very early code. Thanks for the help mate :)

Comment: Right.  Calling `ServerSocket#close()` is what I'm suggesting, which **will** cause the `SocketException` during the `accept()` call.  That's what you want.  I don't think there's any *other* scenario where `close()` can be called.  The client can't call `close()` on the server's socket.  If a client simply closes its own client socket, immediately after connecting, you shouldn't get into that catch block (your server code will have already successfully finished the call to `accept()`).  Again, the link I included in my answer shows quite a bit of agreement on that being the way to close ...

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying now. Also now that I think about it, any other exceptions (including legitimate `SocketException`s) should be handled in that `ReceiveSession`, so you're probably right in saying I should just handle that `SocketException` like that.

Comment: My code wasn't playing nicely with android, so I went with the `SocketException` catch and it turns out `java.nio.AsynchronousCloseException` is not a `SocketException`. I guess I'll just catch that one then.