# Blackberry java, refreshing custom animated banner

Tags: blackberry, java-me, gif, animated-gif

I want to show a .gif banner in the top of my app. I'm using this code to show the animated field [BB Animated GIF Field](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Display-an-animated-GIF/ta-p/445014). The issue is that I want to refresh this banner every minute. I've tried so many things:

- create a new object, but this doesn't change the banner.
- create a new animated field and try to replace it....`IllegalArgumentException`. (I'm trying to change that from inside a `Thread`, using `invokeLater()`...I've used `invokeAndWait()` too)
- remove this animated field and put a new one (from the `invokeLater()` or `invokeAndWait()` -> `IllegalException`)
- setting a bitmap to this field. The first animate doesn't show and I can see an image from the other banner but it isn't animated.

Any ideas?

If you need to see some code, I will try to post it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a minimum BlackBerry OS of 6.0 (or above), the `BitmapField` class [directly supports animated gifs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BitmapField.html).

If you need to support a lower OS version, then you just need to add a method to your `AnimatedGIFField` class to swap out the old image, and use a new one:

```
public void setImage(EncodedImage image) {
    // Call BitmapField#setImage()
    super.setImage(image);

    // Store the image and its dimensions.
    _image = image;
    _width = image.getWidth();
    _height = image.getHeight();
    _currentFrame = 0;

    // Stop the previous thread.
    _animatorThread.stop();

    // Start a new animation thread.
    _animatorThread = new AnimatorThread(this);
    _animatorThread.start();
}
```

Note that this is a UI operation.  So, if you want to update the image from a background thread, make sure to wrap it with a call that puts it on the UI thread.  For example:

```
 final EncodedImage eImage = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("img/banner.gif");
 UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() { 
         _animatedBanner.setImage(eImage);
     }
 });
```

**Update:** I also notice that the way the `AnimatedGIFField` class works is not really good multi-threading practice (for stopping the thread).  If you really want to make the code better, you could [implement this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10961760/119114), or 
[use the technique I show in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16262133/119114).

Read [more about this here](http://forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html).

Comment: Yeah! I'm working with OS 5, and the setImage method works perfect!
Thanks!